# Plot larger points on bottom and smaller on top

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm looking for a way to produce a `scatter` plot in `python` where smaller plots will be drawn *above* larger ones to improve the figure's "readability" (is there a similar word for an image?)

Here's a simple MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def random_data(N):
    # Generate some random data.
    return np.random.uniform(70., 250., N)

# Data lists.
N = 1000
x = random_data(N)
y = random_data(N)
z1 = random_data(N)
z2 = random_data(N)

cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu')
plt.scatter(x, y, s=z1, c=z2, cmap=cm)
plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

which produces:

[image]

I'd like the smaller points to be drawn last so they won't be hidden behind larger points. How could I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apply `sort` before plotting

```
order = np.argsort(-z1) # for desc
x = np.take(x, order)
y = np.take(y, order)
z1 = np.take(z1, order)
z2 = np.take(z2, order)
```

The figure using `alpha` is more readable.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def random_data(N):
    # Generate some random data.
    return np.random.uniform(70., 250., N)

# Data lists.
N = 1000
x = random_data(N)
y = random_data(N)
z1 = random_data(N)
z2 = random_data(N)

order = np.argsort(-z1)
x = np.take(x, order)
y = np.take(y, order)
z1 = np.take(z1, order)
z2 = np.take(z2, order)

cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu')
plt.scatter(x, y, s=z1, c=z2, cmap=cm, alpha=0.7) # alpha can be 0 ~ 1
plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

The output is

[image]